# How do I make a java program read just one line from the file?

Tags: java, arraylist, try-catch, java.util.scanner

So I have my code here:
File text = new File("filename");
Scanner reader = new Scanner(text);

```
        ArrayList<String> employee1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (reader.hasNext()){
            employee1.add(reader.nextChar());
            
        }
        reader.close();
        
        
        
        System.out.print(employee1);
```

Except, I want it so the variable employee1 only is assigned to one line of text, but it assigns the whole textfile to it

The file is:
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Output:
Line 1, Line 2, Line 3

I only need the program to output a file that reads one employee as just one line, as this is what my professor wrote within the assignment.

Comment: Look [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=read+entire+text+file+into+string+variable+java)

Comment: Use 'if' instead of 'while' should do the trick!

Comment: @VitorCavalcanti: Try running it with your suggestion, and see what it does.

Comment: @Kenny: Your ArrayList suggests you want each line to have its own entry into the array.  Is this what you want, or do you want the whole file in a single string variable?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Okay, I mean doing that as a way to achieve the result he wanted, not as a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
File text = new File("filename");
Scanner reader = new Scanner(text);
ArrayList<String> employee1 = new ArrayList<String>();

if (reader.hasNextLine()) {
     employee1.add(reader.nextLine());
}
reader.close();
System.out.print(employee1);
```

But I'm not certain why you want to put one line in an array list.  You can just read in one line as a string and print it like this.

```
String line1 = "File is empty";
if (reader.hasNextLine()) {
     line1 = reader.nextLine();
}
System.out.println(line1);
// do something else with line
```

Comment: It is part of the assignment.